# locate where one 50x50 piece of a larger image is located

Tags: python

Lets say I have a image 1024x1024 and i have a small part of the same image 50x50 and I want to locate where on that image this other 50x50 piece is located. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You may compute the **correlation** between both images.
This can be done by using scipy's `correlate2d` as described in [this tutorial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate2d.html).

Once you have computed the correlation `corr` between both images (`corr = signal.correlate2d(face, template, boundary='symm', mode='same')`), you can then compute the coordinates `x` and `y` of the smaller image: `y, x = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(corr), corr.shape)`.